# Getting the last rows from each of several series in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using postgres as a backend to store sensordata. Various sensors are logging with different frequencies. I want to get the last of each distinct value. I.e. I have the following table:

```
   id   | sensorid | type |   value    |           datetime            
--------+----------+------+------------+-------------------------------
 302888 |        9 |  118 |       4829 | 2017-12-12 22:20:04.911429+01
 302887 |        9 |  116 |      17000 | 2017-12-12 22:20:04.90125+01
 302886 |        9 |  104 |      40400 | 2017-12-12 22:20:04.827895+01
 302885 |        5 |  116 | 4294958596 | 2017-12-12 22:19:04.813092+01
 302884 |        5 |  104 |      76100 | 2017-12-12 22:19:04.803245+01
 302883 |        5 |  118 |       3976 | 2017-12-12 22:19:04.753291+01
 302882 |        5 |  116 | 4294958596 | 2017-12-12 22:16:18.730765+01
 302881 |        5 |  104 |      76100 | 2017-12-12 22:16:18.720933+01
 302880 |        5 |  118 |       3976 | 2017-12-12 22:16:18.700545+01
 302879 |        1 |  118 |       5410 | 2017-12-12 22:15:54.688361+01
 302878 |        1 |  116 |      19000 | 2017-12-12 22:15:54.67866+01
 302877 |        1 |  104 |      33700 | 2017-12-12 22:15:54.660863+01
 302876 |        9 |  118 |       4892 | 2017-12-12 22:15:04.646695+01
```

and so on.

I want to get out the following data:

```
   id   | sensorid | type |   value    |           datetime            
--------+----------+------+------------+-------------------------------
 302888 |        9 |  118 |       4829 | 2017-12-12 22:20:04.911429+01
 302887 |        9 |  116 |      17000 | 2017-12-12 22:20:04.90125+01
 302886 |        9 |  104 |      40400 | 2017-12-12 22:20:04.827895+01
 302885 |        5 |  116 | 4294958596 | 2017-12-12 22:19:04.813092+01
 302884 |        5 |  104 |      76100 | 2017-12-12 22:19:04.803245+01
 302883 |        5 |  118 |       3976 | 2017-12-12 22:19:04.753291+01
 302879 |        1 |  118 |       5410 | 2017-12-12 22:15:54.688361+01
 302878 |        1 |  116 |      19000 | 2017-12-12 22:15:54.67866+01
 302877 |        1 |  104 |      33700 | 2017-12-12 22:15:54.660863+01
```

So I want the row with highest id or datetime for each sensorid and type combination. Is this doable with one sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT
A.ID, A.SENSORID, A.TYPE, A.VALUE, A.DATETIME
FROM
(
    SELECT
    ID, SENSORID, TYPE, VALUE, DATETIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SENSORID, TYPE ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RNUM
    FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
) A
WHERE A.RNUM = 1;
```

**EDIT** FYI I have used ordering by `ID`. Based on your question, it seems that highest `ID` means the latest. So it should make sense. It could also be done by `DATETIME` if the logging happens in a chronological way and you are looking to get the latest records.

Comment: also include `value` in `partition by`.

Comment: I don't think that would be required. But in case two records were simultaneously logged with same `SENSORID` and `TYPE`, I think a `DENSE_RANK` would be a better way?

Comment: Good point Vashi, but in my application it can never happen. (Each sensorid points to a distinct atmega board and type points to a type of measurement taken by that board, the board will send wake up at a certain frequency and send it measurements)

Answer (score 2):

I like `distinct on` for this purpose:

```
select distinct on (sensorid, value) sd.*
from sensordata sd
order by sensorid, value, datetime desc;
```